# Can a single document become referral document for multiple documents in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb I am not able to find any references or link relevant to my scenario.
The scenario is: -
Actually in my scenario I have created 3 documents with name -
Document1
Document2
Document3

the Document3 is the one which has date relevant to both Document1 and Document2
But Document1 and Document2 are not related.
I would like to know how does this scenario is valid way Mongodb.
If it does than can anybody tell me syntax to achieve this.

that is syntax to create document in such form.

For example: -
Consider following 3 Documents: -

```
1] Order.
2] Customer.
3] Vendor.
```

when the Customer is responsible to create Order request.
The Vendor is responsible to Process the order request.
In this scenario how can I Create and store the reference of both customer and vendor associated with that order in Order document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us some concrete sample data so we understand your intention a little better.

Comment: Hi dnickless the above is the scenario which I am trying this scenario for.And my sincere apology for delay response.